# How to set user passwords using passwd without a prompt?

Tags: password

I am writing a script to add a large amount of users to a system. Part of this involves setting default passwords for each user. How can I set users' passwords without it prompting me for the password up front?

Unfortunately passwd doesn't seem to take an argument stating the new password to set. I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try usermod:

```
usermod --password PASSWORD USERNAME
```

The only thing is this needs a pre-encrypted password string which you'd have to generate first.

In order to generate the encrypted password you can use `openssl`. For example:

```
usermod --password $(echo MY_NEW_PASSWORD | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) USERNAME
```

Comment: ...which I can generate using mkpasswd. Excellent, thanks!

Comment: You can also use openssl to generate the encrypted password. For example: `usermod --password $(echo my_new_password | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) USERNAME`

Comment: Three years too late.  I couldn't make the answer  @EricSmith, but I did discover a simpler version of the command that did work: `usermod --password $(openssl passwd -1 {password}) {username}`

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 20

Comment: Always a good idea to put the `PASSWORD` in single quotes since it may contains one or more `$1`,`$2`... which you don't want to be substitued (i.e. for nothing, falsifying the hash). `usermod --password '$HASH' $_user`

Answer (score 33):

You should look at the `chpasswd` command (if available in your linux flavor):

```
echo 'userid:newpasswd' | chpasswd
```

Or, you can cat a file listing userid:passwd for each account on a separate line.

That's it.

Comment: this worked for me in `Dockerfile`

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I think that should be:

   echo 'user_name:password' | chpasswd

Comment: `chpasswd` is the obvious answer, but it has a major flaw: the OP wants to write a script, so the plaintext passwords will be stored on disk. If you're on an SSD there is no reliable way to delete the script after use. Worse, if you change the script you'll probably leave previous versions on the SSD.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by Eric Smith's idea, combining `openssl passwd` and `usermod -p` command worked. Generate hashed value of password along with salt value.

```
$ openssl passwd -1  -salt 5RPVAd clear-text-passwd43
$1$5RPVAd$vgsoSANybLDepv2ETcUH7.
```

Then, copy the encrypted string to usermod. Make sure to wrap it with single quote.

```
$ usermod -p '$1$5RPVAd$vgsoSANybLDepv2ETcUH7.' root
```

Check it out in shadow file.

```
$ grep root /etc/shadow
root:$1$5RPVAd$vgsoSANybLDepv2ETcUH7.:17774:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo -e "NEW_PASSWORD\nNEW_PASSWORD" | passwd username
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good solution, just one line:

```
useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 "$pass") "$user"
```

I can add others parameters like -m to create the home directoty, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use password aging, and set the users so that they must change their password on the first login. See this [article](http://nixcraft.com/getting-started-tutorials/732-linux-force-user-set-password-first-time-they-login.html).

Comment: These intended to be FTP-only accounts, but good advice. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
(echo user; echo password) | passwd
```

works for me both in physical host and container, for various OSes (ubuntu xenial,bionic, debian9,10, centos75,76, coreos)

```
echo user:password | chpasswd
```

works for some OSes, but some OS such as debian9,10 will show an error `can not connect to /var/run/nscd/socket` since it use /etc/nsswitch.conf to determine where it store the password.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do this myself and to keep it from being something that can be intercepted either via ps (which could be overcome with changing `/proc`, but that's invasive).  For me, it looks like the best way to do this will be using a tmpfs created in ram and hold all the info there as root only, chmod 600 files.

```
mkdir /mnt/tmp
mount -o size=10M -t tmpfs none /mnt/tmp
<program that opens file in /mnt/tmp/pass, creates lines with user:newpass>
```

Use the `chpass /mnt/tmp/pass` command as others suggested

this 50 reputation to answer things annoys me greatly.