# How to change password using usermod?

Tags: password

I am superadmin of a server and like to change password of an existing user . How can I do that ?

I tried

```
usermod -p 'new-password' john
```

but it didn't worked ?

Comment: the best answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/a/80447/55435, note to checkout the comments as well

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `usermod -p` flag is expecting the data to be the password already in an encrypted format.

Use `openssl passwd` to generate the encrypted data, or do it like this:

```
usermod -p `openssl passwd` (USERNAME)
```

Comment: `openssl passwd` expects a password of 0 to 10 characters.

Comment: One should use `openssl passwd -1,` otherwise openssl will default to -crypt and truncate the password at 8 chars with a "Warning: truncating password to 8 characters" message.

Answer (score 11):

The reason it didn't work is because `usermod`'s -p option expects the password to be encrypted already.

From `usermod`'s man page:

```
 -p, --password PASSWORD
       The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3).
```

To set a password in this way is not recommended.

Instead You should use `passwd <username>`. This should (as `usermod`) be done as root (if you're not changing the currently logged in users password).

To change the password for user foo.

```
sudo passwd foo
```

This will prompt for a new password.

Have a look at the man-page for `passwd` for more info on setting for example expire time.

Good Luck!

Comment: Why isn't setting a password this way recommended? What are the concerns with it?

Answer (score 9):

You may use  `passwd`:

```
sudo passwd USERNAME
```

You need not `sudo` if you're superuser yourself

Comment: `sudo` require root password :)

Comment: @Achu: it's required current user password. But he is superuser.

Comment: What does `superuser` represent?

Answer (score 4):

The way to assign a password with usermod (which is what the OP actually asked for) is to use a `crypt()` hashed password for the `-p` argument.

```
SALT="Q9"
PLAINTEXT="secret_password"
HASH=$(perl -e "print crypt(${PLAINTEXT},${SALT})")
echo "Password Hash = \"${HASH}\""
```

Then use that in your `usermod -p` command line argument:

```
usermod -p ${HASH} john
```

Answer (score 4):

A non-interactive single line command for changing the password of a user:

```
sudo usermod -p `perl -e "print crypt("new-password","Q4")"` john
```

`usermod -p` requires encrypted password to work. Please note the `new-password` will be visible for users who can list the processes.

Comment: Use single-quotes inside the crypt command (thus: double quotes). If you do that, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Something that should be added here is the following.  This method:

```
sudo usermod -p `perl -e "print crypt("new-password","Q4")"` john
```

means that multiple very similar passwords will ALL work.  For example, on Oracle Linux 7.4 server and Ubuntu 17.10 desktop consider:

```
sudo usermod -p `perl -e "print crypt("borkling","Q4")"` orabuntu
```

Now if one does:

```
su - orabuntu
```

you will find that ANY password that starts with `borkling` will work, e.g.

```
borkling88
borklingjars
```

although `borkline` will not work which is because as stated previously any password that has "borkling" as it's prefix will also work when the password is set in this way.

A way to to this that afaik does not have this unwanted side-effect is the following:

(credit for these goes to "Sandeep" here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script)

On RedHaty Linuxes:  (omit the "-G wheel" if you don't want sudo privs granted)

```
sudo useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 ${PASSWORD}) -s /bin/bash -G wheel ${USERNAME}
```

On Debiany Linuxes (omit the -G sudo if you don't want sudo privs):

```
sudo useradd -m -p $(openssl passwd -1 ${PASSWORD}) -s /bin/bash -G sudo ${USERNAME}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just type

```
passwd
```

In this way normal user can change own password without root privilege if  you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

We can use commands `mkpasswd` and `usermod`. This is simple and reliable.

- In order to have the command mkpasswd:

  ```
  apt install whois
  ```
- ```
  mkpasswd -m sha-512 your-secret-password
  ```
- with the result from `mkpasswd`, you can launch usermod like this

  ```
  usermod -p 'the-result-from-mkpasswd' root
  ```

Check the screenshot from my test
[Demo on password change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC4X1.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
USER=$1
PASS=$2
usermod --password $(echo $PASS | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) $USER
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation on how to use this.