# How to change passwords in bulk? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, password, users

Is there a command that will let me change all the user passwords at once? I would like to find an easier way to perform this change for all 32 users on my machine, and doing them one at a time is not efficient. I don't mind about changing root, I just want to change passwords for all accounts, admins and basics.

Thank you for your help.

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Related: [How to set user passwords using passwd without a prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80444/how-to-set-user-passwords-using-passwd-without-a-prompt) (tl;dr - don't, use `chpasswd` instead)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the chpasswd command. This command can only be used as root. Enter the chpasswd command into the command line then enter the name of the user followed by the password, do this for each user. When finished type ctrl+d. ex.

```
your-computer ~ # chpasswd
user1: password
user2: password
user3: password
```

Another way that you can do this is to have a file containing all of the usernames and passwords, int he same format ie. user1: password. create this file using any text editor such as vim or cat. 
Example on creating the file.

```
your-computer ~ # cat > bulkpasswords
user1: password
user2: password
user3: password
```

Then run the chpasswd command(as root) on the file:

```
your-computer ~ # chpasswd < bulkpasswords
```

Hope this helps!

Sources:
https://linoxide.com/linux-command/change-passwords-batch-mode-chpasswd/

Comment: it does help, but im still trying to find a command that will let me change all the passwords with one command, like "sudo passwd {list of users} Password" that way I dont have to type out every users name.

Answer (score 0):

```
_users=(fred mike joe)

for _user in "${_users[@]}"
do
    USERPW=... # wherever you get that from
    HASH=$(echo "$USERPW" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin)
    # single quotes around hash, so coincidental 
    # stuff like $1 in the pw hash survives
    sudo usermod --password '$HASH' $_user"
done
```