# Bash script to automaticly change a given user's password

Tags: bash, scripts, password, users, passwd

So, I know that the passwd command allows me to change my own password, and if run with sudo, allows me to change anyone's password, but what if I want a script to do it?

I have a script that grabs a username from list.txt and attempts to change their password.

I cant figure out how to have it automaticly set that password without me typing it in each time.
I've tried:

`username=john`

`password=12345`

`echo $password | passwd $username`

`echo 12345 | passwd $username`

but I always get the error

```
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but i cant seem to find anyone with the same issue.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to set user passwords using passwd without a prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80444/how-to-set-user-passwords-using-passwd-without-a-prompt)

Comment: Thankyou, i looked all over, not sure how i missed that one