# Having problem to create users through a shell script in Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: server, 20.04, scripts

```
user1=S211050
user2=4000
clear
while [ $user2 -ne 4050 ]
do
    user2=`expr $user2 + 1`
    echo $user1$user2
    useradd -m $user1${user2}
#   passwd -d $user1${user2}
    echo -e "User123\nUser123"| passwd $user1$user2
#   userdel -r $user1${user2}
done
```

This is script which worked in Ubuntu 18.04 Server but presently is not working in Ubuntu Server 20.04. The error is coming when I am trying to set the password of the user, i.e. the password is not set for the user.

Comment: I think you mean to use `chpasswd`

Comment: Related: [How to set user passwords using passwd without a prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80444/how-to-set-user-passwords-using-passwd-without-a-prompt)